# C# code to apply sql queries on a plain text file?

Tags: c#, mysql

I have written a C# code to read from an SQL file and write them into a plain.txt file, so each table of sql now in a separate txt file. Now, the question is I want to write a C# code to apply an SQL Queries such as select, insert etc. to those text file. What kind of a code that can do so? Some kind of query parser will be used?

Comment: Don't really get your idea here. You wanna insert data into txt file and each of them represents a table? Which kind of format you are using to store these data? CSV?

Comment: Edit your post and add your current code will help people to understand what you want to achieve.

Comment: If these files contain queries that you want to execute, what prevents you from doing something like this: `string sqlQuery = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(TargetFilePath);`? If that's not what you want, please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55175101/4934172) to clarify _and_ include what you've tried so far.

Comment: Each file contains a table like customerID and customerName, the file format is a .txt file notepad file. I want the user to write an sql query suc as select*from fileName; it’s like designing an sql software.